# can any process read the target file when my java process renaming the source file

Tags: java, nio

our portal website will read the json file to display the information.
the json file will be generated by jobs wrote by java.

1. I concerned that if the java progress write the json directly, the website process may get an incomplete file because java process is writing the file.
2. so I decide to write the information to a temp file, after the temp file is ok, rename to the target file, so the website process will get the complete json file.
3. but I still concerned when I was renaming the file,  can any process read the intermediate status of the target file. Actually， I don't know how java implements the rename action.

my code is like below:

```
Path source = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/data/temp/temp.7z.bak");
Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling("/data/temp/temp.7z"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: You should be okay.  The file being moved will not be visible to anything else until it has finished being moved.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Source for that assertion?

Comment: @EJP OP is doing a move/rename of a file, not only on the same file system, but in the same folder.  As far as I am aware, on modern FSs this will always (?) be an atomic operation.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I think the move action should be like this, but I haven't googled any source for this assertion to dispel my doubts.

Comment: Are you having doubts about the Java system libraries or the file system?

Comment: in my scenario, the file is in the same folder and same file system, I think I shouldn't doubt about this, now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `ATOMIC_MOVE` option in your method call :

```
Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling("/data/temp/temp.7z"), StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE));
```

Indeed , the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) states that

> ATOMIC_MOVE
>
> The move is performed as an **atomic file system operation** and all other
>   options are ignored. If the target file exists then it is
>   implementation specific if the existing file is replaced or this
>   method fails by throwing an IOException. **If the move cannot be**
>   **performed as an atomic file system operation** then
>   *AtomicMoveNotSupportedException* is thrown. This can arise, for
>   example, when the target location is on a different FileStore and
>   would require that the file be copied, or target location is
>   associated with a different provider to this object.

This should guarantee that the file gets moved entirely without intermediate states.

Note that you will get a `AtomicMoveNotSupportedException` if such an atomic operation is not possible.

Comment: if I use  ATOMIC_MOVE, will the file being moved will not be visible to anything else until it has finished being moved?

Comment: if I use  ATOMIC_MOVE, will the file being moved will not be visible to anything else until it has finished being moved? As I know about the ATOMIC_MOVE, whatever any Exception thrown, only one file will  exist and the target file should be complete. the ATOMIC_MOVE is platform-dependent,  but I can deal this by catch the AtomicMoveNotSupportedException.

Comment: This is the point of an atomic move, the file address should change at once, so  there is nothing like a "partial" file ever.

Comment: Also, digging into the code, it seems that that call will finally call the classes _sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher_ or _sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher_ , which delegate to native "move" or "rename" operation, hence platform dependent , and atomic.